# Tile URL from ESRI MapServer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, tiles, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am attempting to get a raster tile URL from an Esri MapServer.

The MapServer in question is: https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/OPENDATA_VCGI_EMERGENCY_SP_NOCACHE_v1/MapServer

Based off of the documentation [here](https://apps.pdc.org/msf/sdk/rest/index.html#/Map_Tile/02ss0000001n000000/), I would expect the following to return a map tile for 15/9725/11856:
https://maps.vcgi.vermont.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EGC_services/OPENDATA_VCGI_EMERGENCY_SP_NOCACHE_v1/MapServer/tile/15/9725/11856

Instead, it returns a 404. Does that mean that service is not set up for this map server? Or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MapServer that you have put in the question does not support tiles, see this MapServer in comparison https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/  it has tile info mentioned, and thus it supports tiles.